# Object in heap and overriding index operator

Tags: c++, object, overriding, heap-memory

I overrided index([]) operator in my Vector class. When i use stack initialization :

```
Vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(2);
cout<<myVector[0];
```

In this example everything's okay, but if i initialize Vector in heap:

```
Vector<int>* myVector = new Vector<int>();
myVector->push_back(2);
cout<<myVector[0];
```

I get error. Here is my method code:

```
template<class T>
T Vector<T>::operator[](int index) const{
    return array[index];
}
```

Is any solution to avoid compilation error and get working code?

Comment: `myvector` is a pointer, not an object. You cannot use it with operators. Of course there’s als no reason to use a pointer here …

Answer (score 3):

`myVector` is pointer. So use:

```
myVector->push_back(2);
```

and

```
(*myVector)[0]
```

or

```
std::vector<int> &foo = *myVector; foo[0];
```

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake while writing code here. I use '->' im my code with pointer.

Comment: Problem is not the `push_back`, but the `myVector[0]`

Comment: Or `myVector->operator[](0);`

Comment: Or `std::vector<int> &foo = *myVector; foo[0];` ?